# Python TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement an Unbounded Knapsack while calculating the numbers of each item I used. Here's my code:

```
def best(x, items):
    sum = []
    n = len(items)
    opt = [[0 for i in range(0,x+1)] for j in range(0,n+1)]
    items.insert(0,(0,0,0))
    list = [0 for i in items]

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        weight, value, copies = items[i][0],items[i][1], items[i][2]
        for j in range(1,x+1):
            temp = []
            for k in range(0,x//weight+1):
                if k*weight <= j:
                    temp = temp + [[opt[i-1][j-k*weight]+k*value, i]]

            print(temp)
            opt[i][j] = max(temp, key= lambda x: x[0])


    print("OPT: ",opt)
    print("LIST: ",list)
    return opt[i][j]
```

I want to push both the best value and the number of item used into the array, but got this error:

```
temp = temp + [[opt[i-1][j-k*weight]+k*value, i]]
```

`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`

I've tried several different methods and still clueless about what's wrong with this.

Thanks for any help

---

Sorry for the confusion,
so the usage example is: x is the capacity of the knapsack. items are the list of items each with contains it's weight, value, copies.

So expected input and output will be like:

```
print(best(3, [(1, 5, 2), (1, 5, 3)]))
>>>(15, [2, 1])
```

Comment: `[opt[i-1][j-k*weight]+k*value`, adding `k*value` (int) to list

Comment: I tried this reduced version: `temp = temp + [[opt[i-1][j]+k, i]]` and received no error.

Comment: You need to give a usage example, i.e. what is `x` and what is `items`?

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for the note! But weight and value here are mandatory to get the correct answer.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Ah!!! I think that's the problem! Thank you!

Comment: What I meant was, that I removed stuff that was irrelevant to the problem of a `TypeError`. I was trying to run a reduced version of the code to reproduce the error - No Error! What was the problem in the end?

Comment: @quamrana I figured this out based on the first answer above, it's that `[opt[i-1][j-k*weight]` is a list and `k*value` is an int, that's what making error to show

Comment: Err... `[opt[i-1][j-k*weight]` is a syntax error. `opt[i-1][j-k*weight]` is one of the ints from `opt`. `[opt[i-1][j-k*weight]+k*value, i]` is a list of an int from `opt` + `k*weight` and `i`.